# Auto align left equations in Office Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Is there option for aligning left equations that are inserted in new row (automatically). Every new equation has option Center.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define defaults like this in Equation Options.

1. Insert an equation (it will be centered, by default) and place the cursor anywhere in the equation.
2. Under **Equation Tools**, on the **Design** tab, click the small arrow in the lower, right-hand corner of the **Tools** group. This will open Equation Options.

   [image]
3. In Equation Options, next to **Justification:**, select **Left**.

   [image]
4. Click the **Defaults...** button to make this the default for all future documents using your current template and then click **OK** to apply changes.

Comment: I wasn't sure where to find this in the ribbon of Word 2019, but I just typed Equation Options in the search button on the ribbon.

Comment: In Word 2021 for Mac, you will find Equation Options under Format in the system menu bar.

Comment: In Microsoft Office Home and Student 2019, equation option is in Conversion instead of Tools